# Is there a way to play Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask on the PC?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, zelda-majoras-mask

I remember starting Majora's Mask, loving every minute of it, then having to go off to college and leave the N64 at home with the family. Now that I'm done, and my younger siblings have long since broken our N64, is there a way for me to restart (and finish!) my adventures on the PC?

Comment: Not without an illegal copy of the n64 cart.

Comment: Shame. I was hoping there might be a site similar to GoodOldGames.com, but for old console games.

Comment: Or a legal copy of a cart you own, depending on your jurisdiction! :P

Comment: Project64 has proven very good. I recommend using the Saitek P2600 controller (or anything with 6 buttons on the right-hand grip... in the past, it was harder to find USB controllers modeled after the N64 layout).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best (Legal) way to play it is with the Wii, where you can download a copy for 1000 Wii points (About $10)

Also, it has been released for the 3DS.

Comment: Awesome! My family has a Wii. That'll give me something to do during holidays!

Comment: Keep in mind you need a classic controller or Gamecube controller to play N64 games.

Comment: And also that there's no vibration even if you use the GC controller, so some hidden grottos will be impossible to find with in-game clues.

Comment: There is also a version for the 3DS

Answer (score 2):

Majora's Mask has a remake for the Nintendo 3DS now.  MSRP is $39.99 USD.

Series producer Eiji Aonuma took the opportunity to fix a bunch of things he thought were problems in the original.  These include:

1. Discoverability of sidequests.  For a game based mainly on sidequests, it's difficult to actually FIND some of them unless you're in the right place at the right time.  Now, the Bombers will tell you "rumors" they've heard about quests, which will appears in a new section of the Bomber's Notebook.  Each of the 4 Bombers (not counting Jim) will tell you at most one rumor during each 3-day cycle.
2. Speaking of the Bomber's Notebook, it's had an overhaul.  The new default view shows quests rather than the timeline.  As you complete parts of a quest, it will complete in the notebook.  The old view can be accessed via the Schedule button, but it has a lot more entries on it as everyone who has a sidequest, important or not, is now on there.
3. Boss battles were unintuitive in the original. It's now much easier to figure out what you need to do to beat a boss... and some bosses even have multiple ways to beat them.
4. The song of Double Time has been revamped.  You can now go to any hour in the current day or to the Dawn of the next day.
5. The save system has been changed.  You no longer have to reset to day 1 to save.

   - On the flip side, the game no longer saves when you go back to day 1, so remember to save at an owl statue.

There's also a new fishing minigame, but I've not tried it yet.

Comment: As a side note to the Bomber's Notebook, it remembers specific things for you, such as where the frogs are that you've used Don Gero's mask on.  Not only does it store their location, but the quest log highlights when you've used the mask on one of them during the current 3-day cycle.

Comment: I've heard that some of the changes to the 3DS version affect the atmosphere/ambiance of the game (as well as 3DS OoT) negatively. Is there any truth to that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you live, the law might actually be on your side. In some jurisdictions, you can make backup copies of the ROM on your PC (or use any devices necessary to run your bought software, including cracks) legally.

Comment: If you own the cart and some kind of ROM dumper hardware.